# When will DllMain be called with the DLL_PROCESS_VERIFIER flag?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, dll, dllmain

On Windows, the standard DLL entry point is called DllMain. The second parameter is a DWORD, `ul_reason_for_call`.

I have looked up the possible values for this second parameter on MSDN. The following are obvious:

```
DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
```

But what about:

```
DLL_PROCESS_VERIFIER
```

When will the entry point be called with this flag? Should I worry about it during 'normal' operation of the DLL?

Note that I only see `DLL_PROCESS_VERIFIER` in header files from Visual Studio 2005, not 2008.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I guess in theory Microsoft could invent new usages and flags any time they feel they need a new one. So the simple rule is to ensure that your code tolerates unexpected values: i.e. write it to handle the cases that you need to handle and ignore the rest, by returning zero.

Comment: Agreed. Currently my code is 
{ case DLL_PROCESS_VERIFIER: 
  default: 
     return 0; 
} 

However my question relates to when / why this would currently happen.

Comment: The general consensus seems to be its probably sent as a result of dlls being invoked in a process being measured by Application Verifier. Which is shipped as part of visual studio Im sure, so it should be "easy" to put some kind of logging code, and test to see if it is. during normal operation? obviously never.

Comment: I advise *against* mentioning it explicitly in your switch statement, @Whyam. It gives the false impression that you've given thought to how your program should handle that value, when you obviously couldn't have since you don't know what it's for. By including it in your code, you're inviting future maintainers of the code to ask you what it's for, which will waste your time and theirs. It's best to just pretend it doesn't exist at all.

Answer (score 1):

This is really obscure.  It is not ever documented in [the SDK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682583%28VS.85%29.aspx) and doesn't appear in the SDK header files.  Google produces only a few hits, most sites are down or untrusted.  The only decent hit I get is XBox code, it only declares it but doesn't actually use it.

I'm not sufficiently convinced that this is a real code that you'd ever encounter in a regular Windows program.

Comment: +1 for the msdn link. I didn't actually see that one because I was simply googling for 'DLL_PROCESS_VERIFIER'. The only reason I found it was because I was poking around in the header files.

Comment: It doesn't get passed to ordinary DLLs, only those specially listed in a `VerifierDlls` registry entry.  See https://skanthak.homepage.t-online.de/verifier.html

Answer (score 0):

I think it can have then value if it is run through [Application Verifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms220931.aspx). Kind of guessing :)